# How to edit the data in datagrid window forms in asp.net using sqlite

Tags: asp.net, winforms, sqlite, c#-4.0

i have dovelop a small windows form application using sqlite ,in that form i'm using Datagrid .my question is i want edit and delete a record when i click a button in datagrid
how can i find id value...please any body help me........

Comment: Why do you have the aspnet tag ?

Answer (score 0):

You, have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddtce152.aspx#Y100) which will give you some idea about how to manipulate the datagrid

Comment: Thank you giving a response .i want find the fieldvalue to delete a record from the database using primary key id....